How to Use Predefined Consent Cookies with Scrapy and Splash for Google Scraping?
I’m working on a project where I need to scrape data from Google. Since I’m based in Europe, I encounter the consent popup for cookies. My approach was to send a predefined consent cookie with every request to avoid the popup. However, it doesn’t seem to work as expected.
Here’s the code I’m using:
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

lua_script = """
function main(splash)
    splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
    splash:go(splash.args.url)

    return {
        cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
        html = splash:html()
    }
    end
    """

class ScrapingGoogle(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraping_google"
    allowed_domains = ["splash", "google.com"]

    cookies = [
        {"name": "SOCS", "value": "value_of_the_cookie_found_within_my_browser"}
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.google.ch"
        yield SplashRequest(
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse,
            endpoint="execute",
            args={"lua_source": lua_script, "cookies": self.cookies}
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.css("button.VfPpkd-LgbsSe").get()
        yield {"name of the page": name}

What I’ve Tried:

Retrieved the cookie value (SOCS) from my browser’s developer tools.
Sent the cookie with SplashRequest in the cookies argument.

Observed Behavior:
Despite sending the cookie, the consent popup still appears, and I can’t proceed to scrape the data.
Expected Behavior:

The predefined cookie should bypass the consent popup and allow me to scrape the page directly.

Question:
Am I passing the cookies correctly in SplashRequest, or am I missing something? How can I ensure Google recognizes the cookie and bypasses the consent popup?
